# Dummies guide to bit shifting?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ansi-c

I'm currently in C course and we are working on bitshifting to pack a date. I understand the concept of shifting but I am at a loss for the rudimentary stuff like how many places to shift and how to formulate the mask, so I can pull them back out. Any direction or recommended reading would be great.

I've got this far :-(

```
 #define DAY_MASK  0x???

 #define DAY_OFFSET  ?

 #define MONTH_MASK  0x???

 #define MONTH_OFFSET  ?

 #define YEAR_MASK  0x???

 #define YEAR_OFFSET  ?
```

Thanks

Comment: I just realized that and deleted my comment... But too late ; )

Comment: Start with Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation and ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: How many bits are you using for each field?

Comment: Are you limited to the number of bits? Are there any specific requirements when it comes to the representation of the date?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean C course(Not Class). The assignment is to use the least amount of bits to pack the date. i.e. max value of DAY would be 31, max of MONTH would be 12 and YEAR with a max value of 99. Even after wiki'ing and google'ing, I'm still a bit lost. How do I figure out just how man bits to shift for the digit(s) 31, then how do I derive the mask to & it back out?

Comment: @user1155077: Start by figuring out how many bits are needed to represent each of those three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want 5 bits to days, 4 bits to month, and all the rest to year, something like:

```
#define DAY_OFFSET 0
#define MONTH_OFFSET 5
#define YEAR_OFFSET 9
#define DAY_MASK 0x1F
#define MONTH_MASK 0x1E0
#define YEAR_MASK (~0x1FF)
```

note that I use the ~ operator in year, so it will work on any machine (with no care to the size of int except that it should be large enough to contain the date)

edit: If you (like me) feel not natural with hex numbers, you can use binary:

```
#define DAY_MASK 0b11111
#define MONTH_MASK 0b111100000
#define YEAR_MASK (~0b111111111)
```

and then you can clearly see which bits every field use.

Comment: How did you derive the offset? and Hex values? That is where I am confused.

Comment: the hex are converted from the binary. I just decide which bits should represent which field, and define a mask that has 1 for this bits. the offset is just how much 0s are in the right of the 1s.